# What is the difference in sending http requests using pipe and without using pipe in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5

In my current Angular project I am handling http requests with and without pipe.Both methods I am getting the results.So I want to know what exactly pipe will do.
Below is my sample code.

```
return this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password }));


return this.http.post(API_URL+URI, model)
        .pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError('create', model))
        );
```

Comment: As i've mentioned below: Those (pipe) operators are pure functions that can be used as standalone operators instead of methods on an observable

Comment: @Vinko Vorih When I am using pipe method,whenever an error happens the catchError method is calling and working fine,but at the same time it is not going to the error handler inside the subscribe method..it is going to success part...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pipe method was introduced in the latest versions of RxJS which assists in tree shaking. In this case the operators are pure functions which may be provided as arguments to the `pipe` method (see example bellow).

The traditional way of using operators (instance methods):

```
Observable.operator1().operator2().operator3();
```

The new way of doing the above:

```
Observable.pipe(
operator1(),
operator2(),
operator3()
);
```

The traditional way of using the static methods:

```
Observable.staticMethod1();
```

The new way of using the static methods:

```
staticMethod1();
```

The way how we import resources also differ from traditional and new way,  look this [migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md) for further details:

Comment: can you please explain bit more?what is the exact use of pipe?Is there any benefit of using pipe ?

Comment: Those operators are pure functions that can be used as standalone operators instead of methods on an observable

Comment: you can create your own operator as well and just 'pipe' it to existing code.